# Chrome Extension: popup.html closes and opens response in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I've got a login form on my popup.html which calls the following function...

```
 chrome.extension.sendRequest({
        req: "login",
        user: username,
        pass: pass,
        remember: remember
    }, function(response) {
        console.log("RESPONSE RECIEVED HOOORAH!");
            });
```

this function in turn goes to the following switch statement in my background.html..

```
do_login(request.user, request.pass, request.remember, false, true, function(response){
                        if(response == true){
                            sendResponse("success");
                        }else{
                            sendResponse("badLogin");
                        }
                    })
```

the following is the contents of `do_login`. During the execution of do login my popup.html randomly closes and reopens in a new tab, the code is completed there and I'm logged in. Why is this happening?

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET",requrl,true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(do_login){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4){
            if(xhr.status == 200){
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                try{
                    //Incase they were just logged in as another user.
                    createContextMenu();
                    //users info.
                    var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    if(resp.default === void(0)){
                        logOut();
                        callback(null);
                    }
                default = resp.default;

                for(var i=0;i<resp.s.length;i++){
                globalStaks[i] = resp.s[i];
                }
                st = global;
                bud = resp.bud;
                msg = resp.msg;
                stakid = resp.default;
                }catch(x){
                // This situation is where you have incorrect password
                console.log("something is wrong with logging in ")
                clearLoginInfo();
                console.log("Incorrect password");
                }
                if(resp.msg == "denied")
    {
        clearLoginInfo();
        callback(false);
    }
    else
    {
        loggedIn = true;
        user = username;
        userid = resp.userid;
        if(refresh){
            refreshpage();
        }
        if(notificationdisplay){
            notification.cancel();
        }
        if(remember)
        {
            clearLoginInfo();
            storeLogin(username,pass);
        }
        localStorage.setItem("pass",pass);
        md5 = pass;
        callback(true);
        }
        }else {
            callback(false);
        }
    }
}
        xhr.send(null);
```

**EDIT**

It appears as the last error recieved `background.html` throws.. `Attempting to use a disconnected port object`

full trace is...

```
 Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
 chrome.Port.postMessagechrome/RendererExtensionBindings:147
 chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnConnect.connectEventchrome/RendererExtensionBindings:89
 sendResponse.reply background.html:1266
 xhr.onreadystatechange
```

Answer (score 0):

The code and data in a popup is ephemeral, in that as soon as the popup closes the associated code closes with it, therefore any callback from say a background page to the popup will fail (there is nothing to call back to).

You need to find what is opening the new page (not all your code is included in the question - what does createContentMenu do?).  Desktop Notifications can cause you to lose focus and thus potentially close the popup.

Also make sure you catch the form submit in your popup and then pass the request through XMLHttpRequest (or use an embedded imframe to host the form), as form submission in a popup doesn't work as you might think (you page will not update inside the popup).